# ng-options - pass key instead of value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

This is an ng-option select I'm using:

```
<select ng-model="languagePicker" ng-options="language for (key,value) in getLanguages()" ng-click="pickLanguage(0,languagePicker)"></select>
```

Passing languages2 in the chooseLanguage function makes it pass the value. I'd like to pass the key. How do I do it? Tried gooling it but no luck with how to do that in objects.

This is an example of what .getLanguages() returns:

```
{
"pl-PL":"Polish",
"en-GB":"English"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in getLanguages()"
```

Comment: So simple! Thank you very much!
Going to make it best answer as soon as the timer is off.